az funcapp publish .net8 Isolated breaking Azure configuration runtime settings on Sync
I have an azure functions project that I have upgraded from .net5 -> .net 8.
In the upgrade path, I have come across many issues in specifying that the function app is dotnet-isolated, and using the correct version of .net.
My solution so far has been to run the publish command in my pipeline like so:
func azure functionapp publish ${{ parameters.funcAppName }} --no-build --dotnet-isolated --dotnet-version '${{ parameters.dotnetVersion }}'
I'm passing dotnetVersion as 8.0, but during the sync of the publish, the function app configuration settings drops the .net version. If I change it to '.NET 8 Isolated' mid sync, the sync will complete, but just passing 8.0 as the version doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? The documentation on publish seems behind, and incomplete right now.
Thank you.

The real issue lied in the azure functions core tools version. The pipeline was using v3, when I updated to v4, the publish succeeded.


az funcapp publish .net8 Isolated breaking Azure configuration runtime settings on Sync. Any ideas?

Yes, it will only sync with .NET 8 Isolated as currently only .Net 8 Isolated Version is available for Azure Functions either in Cloud or Local and According to this Document , it says .Net 8 is not used now, may be in next update it can used and AFAIK, this is limitation with .net 8.
Even while creation only Isolated Version is available:



I know that it has to be .net 8 Isolated, but if I pass --dotnet-isolated it defaults to .net5 in the publish process, and passing --dotnet-version of '8.0' fails to sync the functions, and instead drops the .net version in settings in Azure. I'm trying to get the publish to work successfully with .net8 and the isolated process as it should be

Yes, you are correct, AFAIK, this is a limitation with this command.
